# escaping backslash printing two backslashes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html-escape-characters

I am just trying to set a variable string that is going to be a classic asp include, and need to contain backslashes in the string URL, but escaping with an extra "\" is not working.  This line;

```
function addWidget(el){
    var widgetAdd = "<!--#include virtual='backoffice\\home\\widgets\\" + el + ".asp-->";
}
```

returns the string of;

```
"<!--#include virtual='backoffice\\home\\widgets\\example.asp-->"
```

I just want the string to contain the proper url with single backslashes not double.  If I remove the escaping backslash the string is;

```
"<!--#include virtual='backofficehomewidgetsexample.asp-->"
```

thank you

Comment: Your code works in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lygus/ It returns a string with single slashes

Comment: man, in IE10 all Browser Modes and Standards modes i'm getting double backslashes returned in the debugger and it's not working correctly.  Any idea what might cause that?

Comment: You do have a lone quote (`'`). I wonder if that needs to be completed. Other than that, not sure.

Comment: i did notice that im going through trying to resolve with it, it's starting to work correctly when i closed out the lone quote, but still returning double backslashes in IE, i guess if it ignores it i'll be alright. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see exactly what you want.. you want the double backslashes or not? if yes do this

```
function addWidget(el){
     return "<!--#include virtual='backoffice\\\\home\\\widgets\\\\" + el + ".asp-->";
}
```

returns `"<!--#include virtual='backoffice\\home\\widgets\\" + el + ".asp-->"`
you need to escape **each** backslashe. so one for each = 2 more = `\\\\`

if you want to have only one backslash,

```
function addWidget(el){
    return "<!--#include virtual='backoffice\\home\\widgets\\" + el + ".asp-->";
}
```

should work: it returns `"<!--#include virtual='backoffice\home\widgets\" + el + ".asp-->";`

Comment: im looking for the single slashes, but it's not working in IE10, works fine in chrome and firefox, good old IE of course.

Comment: you can still give a shot to `\u005C`